# SoapUI Maven plugin has weird dependencies

Tags: maven, soapui

I'm trying to use the SoapUI Maven plugin as shown here: http://www.soapui.org/Test-Automation/maven-2x.html

I can't add the eviware repository, since I'm behind a corporate firewall (only the browser can connect to the outside world) and have to use the local artifactory repo (which mirrors maven central).

So I tried downloading the appropriate jars and poms from the eviware repo and adding them to the local artifactory. Now it seems I've gone down the rabbit hole, the SoapUI plugin has more and more dependencies that I need to add. At first I didn't mind, but we're looking at tens of jars now, and most of them seem to be things that *should* be in maven central. But then I saw that most of these have altered group-IDs - for example there is a jetty dependency that uses "jetty" as group-ID instead of the canonical "org.mortbay.jetty". And this seems to be the case for many of these dependencies.

So my question has two sides: What are the SoapUI folks doing here? This seems fishy to me, or am I overlooking something?

And second, can I somehow make the plugin use the canonical jars instead of having to chase all the stuff that's in eviware's repository?

Comment: Hi Carl, did you ever get to the bottom of this? I'm in exactly the same situation at the moment just working through the dependencies list. It's a pain point I'd like to avoid if at all possible!

Comment: I never found a really satisfactory solution to this. We ended up adding all the artifacts from the eviware repository to our own local repo. I still think what the SoapUI folks are doing feels very wrong. But I found no other way to make it work.

Comment: Did you try modifying the plugin .pom file to change the dependencies to use the the maven-central "versions"? I also note that the plugin has been recently updated with a new groupid and name: com.smartbear.soapui and soapui-pro-maven-plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look on [this soapui forum](http://forum.soapui.org/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=20368&p=47337#p45977), I explain why soapui uses weird maven coordinates and what could be done to use regular ones.

I have already complained about the problem on [this post](http://forum.soapui.org/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=20964#p48209) and I am sure that SoapUI dev are aware of the problem. Sadly, there is no current work to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried relentlessly to use the maven-soapui-plugin, but It didn't work for me. However the maven-soapui-extension-plugin mentioned by pppeater and developed by redfish above has worked fine when I tried it. I have used artifactory as my repo manager.

1. First configure the plugin on your pom

   ```
   <plugin>
       <groupId>com.github.redfish4ktc.soapui</groupId>
       <artifactId>maven-soapui-extension-plugin</artifactId>
       <version>4.6.3.0</version>
       <executions>
             <execution>
                 <id>soapui-tests</id>
                 <phase>verify</phase>
                 <goals>
                  <goal>test</goal>
                 </goals>
         </execution>
       </executions>
       <configuration>
           <projectFile>${basedir}/src/test/soapui/airline-sample-soapui- project.xml</projectFile>
           <outputFolder>${basedir}/target/soapui</outputFolder>
           <junitReport>true</junitReport>
           <exportwAll>false</exportwAll>
           <printReport>false</printReport>
       </configuration>
     </plugin>
   ```
2. You still need to add the soapui plugin to your repo manager remote repositories and virtual repositories list using the url http://www.soapui.org/repository/maven2/

Answer (score 0):

Just came across this plugin: https://github.com/redfish4ktc/maven-soapui-extension-plugin which notes: "starting from soapui 3.6.1, almost all SmartBear plugin versions have missing dependencies. This is fixed in maven-soapui-extension-plugin"

It also appears to address some Groovy dependencies which others have noted as an issue with the plugin.